# pc sudden black screen

Tags: windows-7, desktop-computer, black-screen-of-death

my pc started to give sudden black screens and becomes unresponsive,
like I use it for a while and all of a sudden it turns black screen,
after that nothing helps

**even reset doesn't help**, it's like the reset button does nothing when it turns black

what I do is I turn it off by holding the power button,
leave it for about about 1 hour and only after that I can turn it on and hear the beep, bios, windows etc (windows 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable cause is overheating. Once the piece is too hot the computer turns off until it is cooled down.

It is also possible that the power supply is out of order. You could try to exchange it and see if the problem persist.

Comment: I changed my all graphics settings to max performance (low quality) and seems to be working now